# When using Rouché–Capelli theorem should I check rank of augmented matrix if rank of coefficient matrix is max?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

I have to solve a system of equations using Rouché–Capelli theorem. In the system there is an unknown coefficient.
I have a couple of cases for the coefficient. As Rouché–Capelli theorem says I need to check the ranks of both matrices and if they are the same the system will have a solution.

My question is, if I already checked the rank of coefficient matrix (for one case) and it is equal to the max possible rank, should I check the rank for the augmented matrix or is it equal to the rank of coefficient matrix by default and doesn't need checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the system be $Ax=b$. If the coefficient matrix $A$ is $(m\times n)$ with $m>n$, then the augmented matrix must be checked, because it is still possible that $\operatorname{rk}[A\mid b]=n+1$. If $m\le n$, it is not necessary, because then $m=\operatorname{rk}A$ and $\operatorname{rk}[A\mid b]\le \min(m,n+1)=m$.